# jQuery: Looking for slideshow/slider plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jquery's plugin that will constantly slide some elements from e.g right to left and when I move a mouse pointer over an element, the animation stops. When I move the mouse pointer out, the animation continues. Did You find that plugin ? I've seen that but I can't remember where.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There quite a lot of **jQuery powered** sliders that can do such job. **Here are just a few** that should fall under your requirements (I'm just not 100% sure on "constantly right to left" requirement -- if fade in/out (or similar effects) counts as "right to left" the it will be fine):

- Nivo Slider - http://nivo.dev7studios.com/
- FlexSkuder - http://flex.madebymufffin.com/
- Orbit - http://www.zurb.com/playground/jquery_image_slider_plugin
- jqFancyTransitions - http://workshop.rs/projects/jqfancytransitions/
- AnythingSlider - http://css-tricks.com/3412-anythingslider-jquery-plugin/

**Standalone** slider:

- Sliderman.js - http://www.devtrix.net/sliderman/examples.html

Comment: FlexSlider is working great for me on Magento, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All what you need is here:

http://www.webdesignshock.com/100-best-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/

Just select which suites your needs. Easy to integrate and many customizable options available with documentation and demos.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

[Nivo slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/) is a good choice. It has plenty of [options to configure](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/#usage), it's free and well documented.

Comment: It is customary to support answers with a reason :)

Comment: Added 3 reasons. As the website promotes the plugin's main advantages, I thought it's unnecessary to copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

What about [google?](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+slideshow+plugin)

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/slideview